# How do I turn off a Wiimote on the Wii U?

Tags: wii-u

I was wondering if I can turn off a Wiimote when using the Wii U in the native mode. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into the home menu, choose controller settings, then choose change order. You can also turn Wii remotes off by taking out a battery. Even after you put the battery back in, the remote won’t turn on until a button is pressed.